# Deploying standalone EAR in a weblogic cluster

Tags: weblogic, load-balancing, ear, atg

I have setup a weblogic cluster on two hosts Machine A and Machine B. The nodemanagers of both the machines are reachable from either of the machine and I can start and monitor the managed servers from either of the two machines. I am trying to deploy an standalone EAR from Machine A to the managed server on machine B. But no files are getting pushed on machine B when I do that.

Here are the steps I followed.

1. Installed WebLogic on both the machines
2. Created a Domain on machine A
3. Configured the domain by adding Managed Servers(Production_A and Production_B) and Machines(Machine_A and Machine_B), Node managers for Machine_A and Machine_B,   through weblogic console.
4. Copiedd the domain file structure to the Machine B and enroll it to the WebLogic Domain.

   nmEnroll('/home/weblogic/Oracle/Middleware/user_projects/domains/clusteredDomain', '/home/weblogic/Oracle/Middleware/wlserver/common/nodemanager')

   Success
5. Created and configured the Cluster on both the machines.
6. Configured the data sources on both the machine.

I can start and monitor the managed servers from either of the two machines. But if I try to deploy my EAR(standalone) on Machine A to Machine B, no files are getting pushed to the other machine.

**Do I need to manually copy the EAR to machine B and deploy it from its weblogic console**

How do I ensure that the cluster is working?

Answer (score 0):

I followed [blog]: http://ajinkya-vichare.blogspot.in/2011/04/weblogic-clustering-on-different-host.html "Weblogic clustering on multiple hosts". Then I configured the data sources. Then I deployed the EAR on all the managed servers. Its working..:D